# Classic ASP error: Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed

Tags: oracle, iis, vbscript, asp-classic, odbc

Recently a classic ASP app that interfaces with SQL and Oracle was migrated from windows server 2003 (IIS6) to IIS 8.5 windows server 2012R2. Users are inconsistently getting an error when a connection opens up to Oracle, but not for SQL.

**Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'**

**[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed**

*This is being thrown on 'cn.open' below

```
Set cn = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        cn.ConnectionString = strOracleConnect
        cn.open
```

The server is using Oracle11g 64 bit driver with default ODBC settings. Fetch buffer size 64000, LOBs enabled, cache buffer size, with failover enabled (10/10). Each time it is reported by a user by the time I get to their desk or try it myself I can't reproduce. 98% of the time it works without issue. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated, I feel this has to be a configuration problem but I can't seem to gain any ground on this and it doesn't help that I can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Under IIS Manager, go to

```
Application Pools --> [YOUR APP NAME] --> Advanced Settings 
Enable 32-bit Applications --> Select TRUE 
Load User Profile --> Select TRUE
```

It was worked for me, hope helps for you also..